# Why datetime substraction in Python doesn't subtract days?

Tags: python, datetime

I expect that if I substract two datetimes in Python, I'll get datetime with substracted days, weeks, etc...

Here is my sample. What I get are just substracted hours, minutes and seconds. Date variable is taken from database. On type() function returns datetime.datetime.

```
def elapsed_time(date):
    """
        Custom filter that format time to "x time age".
    :param date:
    :return:
    """
    if date is None:
        return 'No time given'
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    elapsed = (now - date).seconds
    if elapsed < 60:
        return '{} seconds ago'.format(elapsed)
    elif elapsed < 3600:
        return '{} minutes ago'.format(int(elapsed / 60))
    elif elapsed < 86400:
        return '{} hours ago'.format(int(elapsed / 3600))
    else:
        return '{} days ago'.format((elapsed / 86400))
```

My current example:

Given datetime is    2017-07-27 01:18:58.398231

Current datetime is  2017-07-31 20:23:36.095440

Result is            19 hours (68677 seconds)

Comment: Please show a self-contained example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Why aren't you using the built in [`timesince`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince) filter?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm using Flask. But if I find source code, it would be great idea

Comment: The `seconds` attribute doesn't mean "this timedelta in seconds". It's the seconds component of a days-seconds-microseconds representation.

Comment: Add the days -```elapsed.days * 24*3600 + elapsed.seconds```

Comment: Why not use built-in timedelta from datetime library? https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line returns only the 'seconds' component of the difference and does not take into account the days/hours/minutes components of it.

```
elapsed = (now - date).seconds
```

What you need is to use total_seconds() instead of just seconds since that's what you're trying to compare in subsequent conditions. Use it as follows:

```
elapsed = (now - date).total_seconds()
```

The rest of the code remains the same and you will get your desired output.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! I feel so embarrased. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you subtract two datetime objects the result will be a timedelta

```
import datetime as dt
import time

t1 = dt.datetime.now()

time.sleep(4)

t2 = dt.datetime.now()


dt1 = t2 - t1
print(dt1)
print(dt1.total_seconds())
print(type(dt1))


dt2 = t1 - t2
print(dt2.total_seconds())
print(dt2)

print(type(dt2))
```

If the second timestep was earlier than the first one, the results can be irritating. See negative day in example.

`dt.seconds` is only a part of the result, you are looking for

```
timedelta.total_seconds()
```